# Find coordinates of one point in a triangle given the coordinates of the other 2

Tags: geometry, 2d, trigonometry

I have the following information about a 2D triangle:

- The length of all sides
- The coordinates of 2 points

I need to find the coordinates of the last point.

The triangle is not necessarily a right triangle.

Comment: what programming language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you know point A and point B and lengths AC and BC, then finding C is a matter of doing a circle-circle intersection. The two circles in question are the circle with radius AC around A and the circle with radius BC around B. There will be two answers (which makes sense if you think about it: you can always choose which side of the AB to put C on, given the information that you have).